# Scrapy and Selenium loading web page but returns no result in item loader

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

so trying to scrape a dynamic loaded page from jet.com, the actual url is:

https://jet.com/product/Pringles-Pizza-Potato-Crisps-55-Oz/b809dbfac8de4758b3234a82ff562fd5

I've included my spider below, the page loads in the chrome browser, but the loader returns no results. Complete honesty, I'm very new to python and scrapy, and just started playing with Selenium this morning, unfortunately the documentation for using Scrapy and Selenium and an item loader is somewhat hit or miss when you can find it. Any tips would be helpful, I'm afraid its probably an obvious mistake but I can't see it quickly.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from JetScrape.items import ProductLoader, JetProduct
import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
import time



class JetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "jet"
    allowed_domains = ["jet.com"]
    with open("JetURL.txt", "rt") as f:
        start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]

    def __init__(self):
        scrapy.Spider.__init__(self)
        self.br = webdriver.Chrome()

    def _del_(self):
        self.br.close()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.br.get(response.url)
        time.sleep(3)
        Today = datetime.datetime.now()
        jetload = ProductLoader(item=JetProduct(), selector=self.br.page_source)
        jetload.add_xpath("jetprice", "//span[@class='formatted-value']/text()")
        jetload.add_xpath("jettitle", "//h1[@class='name']/text()")
        jetload.add_value("jetLast_Updated", Today)
        yield jetload.load_item()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass a scrapy selector item to the ItemLoader function.

You could try the following modifications:

```
from scrapy import Selector
...
def parse(self, response):
    ...
    br_selector = Selector(text = self.br.page_source)
    jetload = ProductLoader(item = JetProduct(), selector = br_selector)
```

The complete spider code should look something like this:

```
import datetime
import time
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy import Selector
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from JetScrape.items import ProductLoader, JetProduct


class JetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "jet"
    allowed_domains = ["jet.com"]
    with open("JetURL.txt", "rt") as f:
        start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]

    def __init__(self):
        scrapy.Spider.__init__(self)
        self.br = webdriver.Chrome()

    def _del_(self):
        self.br.close()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.br.get(response.url)
        time.sleep(3)
        Today = datetime.datetime.now()
        br_selector = Selector(text = self.br.page_source)
        jetload = ProductLoader(item=JetProduct(), selector=br_selector)
        jetload.add_xpath("jetprice", "//span[@class='formatted-value']/text()")
        jetload.add_xpath("jettitle", "//h1[@class='name']/text()")
        jetload.add_value("jetLast_Updated", Today)
        yield jetload.load_item()
```

If this doesn't work then please post your `items.py` contents so I can reproduce the complete crawler.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the dynamic crawl issue, I started returning a value for jetprice and last updated, I need to confirm my xpath for title and add a few more variables. It does however keep throwing a windows error and says chromedriver has stopped working and shuts the program down. I assume that has something to do with the forced close but it appears you solved my problem. Thanks so much for the detailed response. I did have to change it from br.selector to br_selector as it kept saying br was an undefined global variable.

Comment: Glad to know it worked for you. I have corrected the variable name from br.selector to br_selector in my answer according to your feedback. About your other issues, I suggest you post a new question if you need more assistance. Happy scraping!